CSS scrollbar-gutter causing STATUS_BREAKPOINT on partially loaded page
I think that I just discovered a very specific CSS bug which I'll try to demonstrate:

I have "scrollbar-gutter: stable" set to a DIV element.
I use JS to load cached HTML content to the DIV when hovering over icons on my page (different content based on the icon; using .innerHTML method to load the content).
If I hover over any icon while the page is loading, or the DIV in question itself, the entire website crashes with the STATUS_BREAKPOINT error.
Note that I'm also loading up a large JS array with all the cached HTML inside it directly from PHP (using <script> while previously reading it from SQL), so this would be the "page is loading" time gap in which the crash happens.



The JS code that loads up HTML:
function loadDescriptionBox(itemId, e)
{
    document.getElementById('descbox').innerHTML = items[itemId].html;
}

Example of the items array:
items['c1'] = 
{
    html: 'HTML content here'
}

Has anyone ever experienced something similar?

I tried removing all other CSS lines from that element - I can confirm that having only "scrollbar-gutter" by itself still causes crashes
Removing that one line from the CSS completely fixes the issue.
Tested on Chrome and Edge - crash happens on both.

